# Swiftui pass data from list item to popover

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, popover

I'm new to SwiftUI.  I am trying to pass data from a list (foreach) to a popover.

I can pass data from list item to detail view.
I can pass data from to a popover.

Because the popover is outside of the foreach loop I don't know how to hold the foreach item and pass it to the popover.

I created a @State item of the type.

```
@State var theItem: Meals?
```

and when the list item is clicked, I set the item value to the @State variable to the item. The "meals" is a Core Data array.

```
        List {
            ForEach(meals) { item in
                
            Button(action: {
                theItem = item
                isShowingMealPopover = true
```

The popover is just outside the List.

```
.popover(isPresented: $isShowingMealPopover) {
            ThePopoverView(mm: theItem!)
}
```

In the ThePopoverView I have tried the following:

```
var mm: Meals
// @Binding var mm: Binding<Meals>
// @Binding var mm: Meals
```

I know I am not passing the data because when I click on the list item the app crashes for unwrapping a nil error on theItem.

I tried changing PortionsPop(mm: $theItem) but received error Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Meals?>' to expected argument type 'Binding'

Logically, I believe I am heading in the correct direction. What am I missing?

Any help would be great!

Comment: you could have a look at using `.popover(item: ...)`, see the docs at 
[popover](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/popover(item:attachmentanchor:arrowedge:content:))

Comment: Thank you!  You pushed me back in the correct direction.  I attempted to use .popover(item: $theItem) but was adding the isPresented: $isShowingMealPopover to it as well because I wasn't sure how I would trigger the popup.  I still don't know how it gets triggered but it works!  
Thanks again.